# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code confusion

Tags: c#, sql

I'm a C# newbie

I am getting the error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" when I press the submit button when the app is running

this is my code where i'm getting the error

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtPrice.Text + "','" + txtQuan.Text + "','" + txtURL.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Your Data Stored Succesfully!";
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtPrice.Text = "";
        txtQuan.Text = "";
        txtURL.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Does it happen the second time you click the button? maybe you are trying to connect again after the connection was closed the first time you clicked the button.

Comment: No i only click the button once and I get the error after only one click

Comment: Set some break points on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery.. also wrap that code around a try{}catch{} and just curious... Table is not the name of your table is it...? what is the actual table name..? and change the Insert query to utilize Parameterized Query...

Comment: use what you have in front of you..and what I mean by that is the `INTERNET` google for millions of working examples that are out there..

Comment: No Table is the Name of the Database.

Comment: awesome.. then you just answered your own issue.. you can't insert into a Database.. you insert into a Table.. what Table within your database are you trying to insert data into.. I would respectfully recommend that you do a google search on Databases with C#... DataSource is the Database name.. now I am wondering if your Connection string is setup properly.

Comment: here is a good Tutorial where you can start ..
[C# Tutorial Inserting data into Sql Server using C#](http://mrbool.com/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-csharp-and-asp-net/25091)

Comment: No Sorry I created a table within the database called Table i wasn't thinking when i answered last, the database is called ConnectionString

Comment: then I would suggest changing the name of the Database to something else.. or when ever you use the Insert statement you will need to surround the name of the database with `[Table]` very UGLY change the name and save yourself the headaches.. Don't use `Reserved` words to name tables or Databases

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code. Most obviously, as your error message suggests, you don't catch the exceptions, you don't have any error handling. Generally, database, networking, file IO and other external things like that need error handling. You should open the connection in the same method where you use it and close it, preferably inside a using block. And most importantly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. The very first thing you need to learn about databases is to use parameters, and don't concatenate strings in your SQL.